# Carrierwave file upload not working with searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am facing issue with upload file getting this issue

{"id":2134,"exception":["Searchkick::ImportError","MapperParsingException[object mapping [avatar] trying to serialize a value with no field associated with it, current value [file.jpeg]] on item with id '2134'"],"exception_object":"MapperParsingException[object mapping [avatar] trying to serialize a value with no field associated with it, current value [file.jpeg]] on item with id '2134'"}

Comment: Please show your mapping and the document you're trying to index

Comment: user.rb file or uploder file